# How to show the share button in Mountain Lion?

Tags: cocoa, osx-mountain-lion

Mountain Lion offers a built-in sharing button that reveals a menu of sharing services appropriate for the app:

[image: Share button in Safari 6.0]

How can I insert it in my app?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

To add the share button on Mountain Lion:

**1)** Add a `NSButton` called, for example, `shareButton`.

**2)** Add the standard image for this button:

```
[shareButton setImage:[NSImage imageNamed:NSImageNameShareTemplate]];
[shareButton sendActionOn:NSLeftMouseDownMask];
```

**3)** Into the "on click action", present the `NSSharingServicePicker`:

```
NSSharingServicePicker *sharingServicePicker = [[NSSharingServicePicker alloc] initWithItems:urls];
sharingServicePicker.delegate = self;

[sharingServicePicker showRelativeToRect:[sender bounds]
                                          ofView:sender
                                   preferredEdge:NSMinYEdge];
```

**4)** Eventually, implement the `NSSharingServicePickerDelegate` methods to customize the picker’s available services.

Answer (score 4):

In Swift, I've used this:

```
extension NSSharingService {
    class func shareContent ( content: [AnyObject], button: NSButton ) {
        let sharingServicePicker = NSSharingServicePicker (items: content )

        sharingServicePicker.showRelativeToRect(button.bounds, ofView: button, preferredEdge: NSRectEdge.MaxY)
    }
}
```

Comment: how to use it ?

Answer (score 0):

Note that if you're trying to add this button via Interface Builder:

1. Select the button
2. Switch to Attributes inspector
3. Delete the button Title
4. Insert: NSShareTemplate as the Image name.

It doesn't look right to me in XCode, but works fine when run.

PS - This appears to be a case where [you need to use the System Icon string value](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/applehiguidelines/SystemProvidedIcons/SystemProvidedIcons.html) (NSShareTemplate) instead of the constant (NSImageNameShareTemplate).

Comment: Recommend not using IB to set the image. It just works when setting it via code. In addition, should also add the following line afterwards: "[shareButton sendActionOn:NSLeftMouseDownMask];"