# Mac equivalent of UIBarButtonSystemItemAction

Tags: iphone, macos, cocoa, icons

Is there an equivalent of `UIBarButtonSystemItemAction` on OS X Mountain Lion ? I did go through the `NSSharingService` documentation and could not find anything. It should exist as Preview.app and Safari.app display that kind of icon which is not in their resource files (I did go through the files).

Thanks

Comment: This may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11815077/how-to-show-the-share-button-in-mountain-lion

Comment: If you post this as an answer, I will accept it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a similar question to this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11815077/how-to-show-the-share-button-in-mountain-lion). Glad it could be of some help. I find it interesting that the Mac sdk and the ios sdk are still different in areas like this.