# Mountain Lion Share Menu

Tags: cocoa, osx-mountain-lion

Similar to the [share button that can be created, with NSSharingServicePicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11815077/how-to-show-the-share-button-in-mountain-lion), is it possible to have a share menu, as there is in Safari - [image: Image showing Safari's sharing menu] in my own application?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A few seconds of Googling produces this:

`NSArray *sharingServices = [NSSharingService sharingServicesForItems:items];`

... then you can walk through each of the services and build menu items for them. Taken from [this code sample](https://gist.github.com/4132533).